# How to alias a google web font font-family/font-weight combination?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

TL;DR: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/ericksepulveda/pen/arJpRK)

I'm using the google web font [Poppins](https://fonts.google.com/?query=poppins&selection.family=Poppins:400,600) that has a semi bold style. To use it I have to add:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

I want to know if there is a way (and if there is, how) to alias the combination of font-family and font-weight to a new font family, so that I can use it by just adding:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins Semi Bold';
}
```

(I also added `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600" rel="stylesheet">` to import the fonts)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a class

```
.poppins-semi-bold {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

and use it like

```
<div class="poppins-semi-bold">This is poppins semi bold</div>
```

Comment: That works, but it's exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: you're talking about font-face i see. Check this then https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: I had already seen that link but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my problem :(. The only way I think it can be solved is by downloading the fonts and then making the font-face, but I lose Google's CDN.

Comment: that's because you probably need a .woff version of the font. Try to donwload the font from google, then put it in a folder in your project and follow the steps in the link to create your desired font

Comment: I edited my previous answer to include just what you told me :( I really hope there's a way to do this without having to download them and then also serve them